# Why does server-eval-at seem to change the behavior of read-string?

Tags: server

I am trying to create a script that, when run with emacs, will read commands from stdin a line at a time, execute them in another emacs process (with `server-eval-at`) and print the result. The process should exit when no more input is available. I have come up with a basic protocol and everything seems to work when using `eval` locally, but after introducing `server-eval-at` the emacs process hangs instead of exiting at the end of input.

For initial development I was doing the evaluation inline, in the same process that was reading the input. That seems to work well. That script looks like

```
(while (setq command (ignore-errors (read-string "")))
  (setq command (read command))
  (message "[DEBUG] Received command %s" command)
  (let ((result (eval command)))
    (message "[DEBUG] Response received %s" result)))
```

In a shell script, for easier testing:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$(mktemp -d)"
cat <<EOF > script.el
(while (setq command (ignore-errors (read-string "")))
  (setq command (read command))
  (message "[DEBUG] Received command %s" command)
  (let ((result (eval command)))
    (message "[DEBUG] Response received %s" result)))
EOF

echo '(message "hello world")' | \
emacs --quick --batch --script "$PWD/script.el"
```

An example of running this, with output:

```
$ ./t2
[DEBUG] Received command (message hello world)
hello world
[DEBUG] Response received hello world
$
```

As you can see, the debug messages are printed. The process exits at the end of input.
All of this is expected and OK.

Now I want to run the incoming commands on the server, so I use `server-eval-at`. Here is that script

```
(require 'server)
(while (setq command (ignore-errors (read-string "")))
  (setq command (read command))
  (message "[DEBUG] Received command %s" command)
  (let ((result (server-eval-at (getenv "RPC_SERVER_NAME") command)))
    (message "[DEBUG] Response received %s" result)))
```

Another shell script, for easier testing

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$(mktemp -d)"

export RPC_SERVER_NAME="$PWD/emacs"
emacs --quick "--fg-daemon=$RPC_SERVER_NAME" >stdout.log 2>stderr.log &
sleep 1

cat <<EOF > script.el
(require 'server)
(while (setq command (ignore-errors (read-string "")))
  (setq command (read command))
  (message "[DEBUG] Received command %s" command)
  (let ((result (server-eval-at (getenv "RPC_SERVER_NAME") command)))
    (message "[DEBUG] Response received %s" result)))
EOF

echo '(message "hello world")' | \
emacs --quick --batch --script "$PWD/script.el"
```

An example of running this, with output:

```
$ ./t1
[DEBUG] Received command (message hello world)
[DEBUG] Response received hello world
```

The output looks fine, but the process does not exit!

I have introspected these processes a few ways:

1. top shows that the `server-eval-at` emacs (client) is consuming 100% CPU.
2. strace shows that the `server-eval-at` emacs (client) is calling `read` on stdin (fd 0) repeatedly, and receiving an empty string each time
3. strace shows that the `eval` emacs calls `read` on stdin twice: once to read the command, and once receiving an empty string before exiting.
4. gdb on the `server-eval-at` emacs (client) has a Lisp Backtrace with `read-string` at the top.

I inlined `server-eval-at` and was able to identify that calling [`accept-process-output`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/79d04ae13ff33a93f631061d912168e9703251dd/lisp/server.el#L1739)
is necessary for the subsequent call to `read-string` (in the next loop iteration) to behave differently, but it is hard for me to
dig much deeper than that.

I tried these same steps against emacs 26.3 and observed the same result.

I am using emacs 27.1 on Ubuntu Linux 18.04, as installed with evm.

Comment: Not sure what "but the process does not exit!" means. It seems work as expected here with Emacs 27.1 on macOS. Your code won't quit properly as `read-string` always returns a string (non-nil), and I don't see why you wrap it with `ignore-errors`, the function is not expected to fail. Emacs quits while it encounters an error, such as "End of file during parsing:" from `read` when you does not enter a valid sexp.

Comment: `read-string` signals an error at the end of input, this is easy to verify. `ignore-errors` ignores that error and returns `nil` which will cleanly break out of the loop. After the loop emacs will exit because it is the behavior when running with `--script`/`--batch`. As I mentioned above, all of this behaves as I expect when not using `server-eval-at`. If what you are saying is true, then **not** using `server-eval-at` actually causes emacs to behave incorrectly, but I don't think that's the case.

Comment: You're correct about `read-string`. I didn't realize I can use C-d, normally user can quit the minibuffer via `C-g` which not work in batch mode. I didn't test your exact code, I simply test `server-eval-at`. Your program does not kill the first Emacs process, it remains running after the program ends.

Comment: Also posted to [help-gnu-emacs](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2020-11/msg00405.html)